# Display async web service logs on browser real time using scala and play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, akka

I am working on application using Scala and Play framework. In my application I have to call web service which returns me logs asynchronously. When I am calling same service from command prompt I was getting real time logs on my command prompt.

But the Java Service I'm calling from my Scala and Play framework controller method. Now whatever longs I was receiving on my command same I want to display on my browser real time.

I think I have to deal with "play framework websocket" here or "Akka" but I am not sure how to do it.

I have also tried couple of examples but I couldn't found any small examples for this. Can you please guide me how to deal with this type of requirement?

I'm also fine with another approach if possible using Scala + Play framework + Akka.

Thanks!!

Comment: Websocket is the way to go if you want real time updates ! Here is an example : http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-websocket. And the official doc : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWebSockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a check to this simple and minimal example : https://github.com/ticofab/simple-play-websocket-server

Comment: Thanks @Louis now I have configured websoket at my local server and it is working as expected.